# Is my HSA contribution "individual" or "family" if I had a qualifying event mid year?

Tags: united-states, hsa

I started 2014 with a "family" HDHP.

At the end of February my spouse started a job with her own coverage (not HDHP) and we added our child to her new "individual + child" plan and converted my coverage to "individual."

Is my HSA contribution limit "individual", "family" or something in between?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: something in-between.

There are two key parts to the determination of wheater a person can deposit money under the single plan or the family plan:

- Situation on December first
- Situation each month.

Here is the info on [Form 8889](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-8889,-Health-Savings-Accounts-%28HSAs%29) with instructions

From Line 3 of Form 8889:

> If you were under age 55 at the end of 2013, and on the first day of every month during 2013, you were, or were considered, an eligible individual with the same coverage, enter $3,250($6,450 for family coverage). All others, see the instructions for the amount to enter....

From the instructions for line 1

> If you were covered, or considered covered, by a self-only HDHP and a family HDHP at different times during the year, check the box for the plan that was in effect for a longer period. If you were covered by both a self-only HDHP and a family HDHP at the same time, you are treated as having family coverage during that period. If, on the first day of the last month of your tax year, December 1 for most taxpayers, you had family coverage, check the “family” box.

For the instructions for Line 3:

You see which option applies to you. In the most difficult case you take the first of each month and answer single or family. If single then that month is credited with the annual amount for single, if family then that month is credited with the annual amount for family. Add them up and divide by 12. That is what you can contribute/deduct for the year.